# Modifying the "Original Estimate" field in a TFS Bug

Tags: tfs, field

We've been discussing possible alterations to the TFS work items templates -- Many of our  developers currently use a mental model with a "rough cut" estimate of time when assessing bugs: "This will take a lot of time", "This is an easy fix" or "This is medium effort". They use this as a way to allow PMs to start scheduling and to later populate a firmer effort after research.

We have, I think, two options:

1. Add a new field to the bug WIT for "rough cut estimate" that's just text and allow people to enter freetext.
2. Modify the existing "original estimate" to be a string, and require developers to firm up their estimates to hours.

We're considering #2 because we'd like to stay as "out of the box" as possible. If we choose option #2, are we jeopardizing out of the box reporting in any way? Are there serious ramifications for reporting if we change the field's underlying data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the "requirement" work item type (Scrum: Product Backlog Item, Agile: User Story,  CMMI: Requirement), there is a field where you can store a rough estimate. In Agile it is called Story Points, in scrum Effort.
You can put there any number and I use it with the Fibonnaci sequence. Search on "planning poker" and you get what I am talking about.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you! The one thing that will keep us from implementing is that Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate is a double. There's no capacity for freetext there.